# Flask, why does request.form runs error 400?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to extract text from the following HTML code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    H_desiderata = float(request.form.get('H_desiderata')) #THIS CAUSES THE ERROR
    return render_template('form1.html')
```

HTML below:

```
    <body>
      <h2>Brioche Recipe</h2>
        <form>
          <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item">
      
              <label class="text" for="H_desiderata">
              H_desiderata:
               </label><be>
               <input type="number" id="H_desiderata" name="H_desiderata1" 
               value={{val_H_desiderata}} min="1" max="99" step="1"><br>
```

Before putting it into a grid it worked:

[image]

old working code:

```
<form>
  <label for="H_desiderata">H_desiderata:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="H_desiderata" name="H_desiderata" 
    value={{val_H_desiderata}} min="1" max="99" step="1"><br>
```

How should I adapt request.form to return the value within the input box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is so much wrong with your code, but let's start with this:

`request.form` is empty when `request.method == "GET`.  So. `request.form['H_desiderata']` will give a key error.

Move that to the `POST` section of your view.  Also, use `request.form.get('H_desiderata', -9999999)` in case it's not defined.

**UPDATE:**

OK, now try:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.form)
    print(request.form.get('H_desiderata'))
    print(float(request.form.get('H_desiderata')))
    H_desiderata = float(request.form.get('H_desiderata'))
```

Then, you are going to want:

```
return render_template('form1.html', val_H_desiderata=H_desiderata)
```

**UPDATE2:**

Your `<form>` tag is malformed.  Try:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
```

**UPDATE3:**

You change the name of the input, so change to: `request.form.get('H_desiderata1')`

Comment: I edited the code as you can see on the question as well, however it still runs the same error. If I remove that line the code runs, so request.form is the issue.

Comment: The first two lines return: `ImmutableMultiDict([]), 
None`

Comment: You're going to need to show your `<form></form>` tags in the new html.  Like I said, many problems with your code.

Comment: I tried to use form just outside the 'div' and 'label', same issue

Comment: I solved by erasing the entire code resetting and adding chunk by chunk, I appreciate the time. Your answer will be useful to viewers.